# What is the most elegant way of finding the n-length consecutive sub-lists of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, sublist

Let's say I have `some_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and I want to find all 3 element consecutive sub-lists: `[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]`.

What's the most elegant way of doing this?

Comment: what do you want to get if `some_lst = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> some_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l = [some_lst[i:i+3] for i in xrange(len(some_lst)-2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is slices and `zip`:

```
>>> some_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> zip(some_lst, some_lst[1:], some_lst[2:])
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9)]
```

With `itertools.islice` and `itertools.izip` you can make it more memory-efficient:

```
from itertools import islice, izip
izip(islice(some_lst, 0, None),
     islice(some_lst, 1, None),
     islice(some_lst, 2, None))
```

or

```
izip(*[islice(some_lst, s, None) for s in range(3)])
```

Comment: The question asks for sub-**lists**.

Comment: Good and tricky. I like it. I think `zip(*[some_lst[i:] for i in xrange(len(some_lst))][:3])` is more general way of your first answer .

Answer (score 1):

yet another way:

```
subLists = map(lambda x: some_lst[x-1:x+2], some_lst[:-2])
```

Comment: It works only list of consecutive number which start with 1. But it seems to be fast.

Comment: you're right for a random start use: `subLists = map(lambda x: some_lst[x-1:x+2], range(len(some_lst)-1)[1:])`